# LinkedIn API 2.0

Tags: linkedin, linkedin-api

Есть проблема с новым дизайном LinkedIn Sales Navigator.

На старом дизайне выполнялся такой запрос:

https://www.linkedin.com/sales/search/resultCount?keywords=java&count=25&start=0&updateHistory=true&trackingInfoJson.contextId=487C2F37E591501560AC3C19062B0000

который брал параметры поиска выбранные пользователем.

В новом дизайне урл изменился и выглядит таким образом
https://www.linkedin.com/sales/search/people?keywords=java&logHistory=true&page=1&searchSessionId=HAGIG7aAReq4rKjQkmdf7w%3D%3D

Как мне получить обьект с данными как на старом дизайне?
Спасибо!

Comment: А как Вы уже пробовали и что не получилось? Спасибо.

Comment: @0xdb Запрашивал данные с этого URL и данные приходили в HTML а не в JSON. На старом дизайне по первой ссылке приходил объект.